# Nginx getting the event "ngx_master_****" was not signaled for 5s

Tags: nginx

I am getting Error While running Nginx

[image]

Getting this in error log file **the event "ngx_master_9488" was not signaled for 5s**

I am using Windows Operating System

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 5):

You can specify passphrase in text file, and connect it via **ssl_password_file** directive. Something like this:

```
listen 3001 ssl;

ssl_certificate         cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key     key.pem;
ssl_password_file       pass.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

It will happen when when you enable ssl in nginx with key and pem file generated from openssl having a pass phrase for the key file.

Use the below command to remove the pass phrase from key file and refer the new file (serverunsecure.key) in nginx configuration.

openssl rsa -in server.key -out serverunsecure.key